# showing the function is continuous at a point using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Tags: functions, continuity

I have this question:

 Use the definition of continuous function with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to show that the function $f$, defined as 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\textrm{if } x=0 \\x \sin\frac{1}x &\textrm{if } x\neq0\end{cases}$$ 

 is continuous at $x=0$.

Here is my try.

 Given arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. I'll try to find $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that if $0<|x-0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

for $x=0$, $|f(x)-0|=|f(0)-0|=|0-0|=0<\epsilon$

for $x\neq0$, $|f(x)-0|=|x \sin \frac{1}x-0|=|x \sin \frac{1}x|$

 I choose $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\sin\frac{1}{x}}$ such that if $0<|x|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-0|=|x \sin \frac{1}x-0|=|x \sin \frac{1}x|=||x| \sin \frac{1}{x}|<|\delta \sin \frac{1}{x}|<|\frac{\epsilon}{\sin\frac{1}{x}} \sin \frac{1}{x}|=\epsilon$

 Thus, $(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists \delta >0)$ such that if $0<|x-0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$ or I can say that $f$ is continuous at $0$

I wish anyone can check my answer and correct it if it is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f$ is continious at $0$, you need to show that $\lim(f)=f(0)=0$,

In that case, since you have $0<|x-0|<\delta$, you do not have to check the case $x=0$ (as your inequality shows).

Choose $\delta=\epsilon$,

if $0<|x-0|<\delta$ then $|x\sin (\frac1 {x})-0|<\epsilon$ since $|\sin (\frac1x)|\leq 1$.

**OR**

Directly use continiouty [defination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_definition_.28epsilon-delta.29_of_continuous_functions) and start with $|x-0|<\delta⟹ ...$.

Comment: thank you. I have tried to find $lim(f)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ but I was stuck. Could you continue your last sentence?

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa: I put the links for the defination.

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa: I edit the answer, check it out.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your answer and you should choose $δ≤ϵ$ using that sin(1/x) is bounded by 1 at maximum. The other calculations are correct.

Comment: thank you. So, the $\delta$ I should choose is just $\delta \leq \epsilon$ ? Ah, yeah, I just realized that $|sin \frac{1}{x}| \leq 1$.